# PHP email is sent, but it doesn't include the message

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to build an email form for a contact page. Everything goes well and the email is sent. Apart from being in junk (which I will solve with the server), the email doesn't contain any message, or content so to speak. It has the subject, but no headers and message. Here is the code for it:

```
<?php
$phpSelf = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        echo '
        <form action="'.$phpSelf.'" method="post" class="formular" name="formular-contact">
        <div class="info-client">
        <p class="info-client">Doriti sa ne contactati?</p>
            <div class="informatie">
                <p>Nume:</p><br>
                <input type="text" name="nume">
            </div>
            <div class="informatie">
            <p>Prenume:</p> <br>
            <input type="text" name="prenume">
            </div>
            <div class="informatie">
                <p>Email:</p> <br>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="informatie">
                <p>Mesaj:</p> <br>
            </div>
            <textarea rows="7" cols="82" name="mesaj" id="styled" form="formular-contact"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Trimiteti">
        </div>
        </form> ';
if((isset($_POST['nume'])) && !empty($_POST['nume'])) {
    $nume = $_POST['nume'];
}
if((isset($_POST['prenume'])) && !empty($_POST['prenume'])) {
    $prenume = $_POST['prenume'];
}
if((isset($_POST['email'])) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
if((isset($_POST['mesaj'])) && !empty($_POST['mesaj'])) {
    $mesaj = $_POST['mesaj'];
}
$mesaj = wordwrap($mesaj,70);
mail("contact-email@hotmail.com","$email;$nume$prenume",$mesaj);
?>
```

I know it is basic, and I will add some verifications for empty fields and such, but I want to send the email correctly first. A little bit of insight, I am using a webpage which has an include with the code from above. That is why I have the html form and php code.If there is a better way to do it, I'd really like to know. Thanks!

Comment: Is `$_POST['mesaj']` populated? You don't need the `isset` and `!empty` check, the `!empty` should be enough, it has to be set to be not empty.

Comment: so i used firefox, when to network, hit refresh and looked for POST method.When to its params, and there was no message. i think the textarea is acting up.

Comment: @TakeDown What are you putting in the textfield when you submit?

Comment: a few random letter. i do sometimes put some more logical ones like "test".

Comment: @TakeDown have you tried without the `form` attribute? I dont think it is needed when contained within the form

Comment: but don't i need the form atributte to submit the information? i do not have any other forms

Comment: @TakeDown you need the form attribute if your `<textarea>` is outside your `<form>`. But in your case the textarea is contained within your form. Currently your `<input>` tags do not have this attribute because they are contained within the form as well.

Comment: Thank you very much.This worked wonders.

Comment: @TakeDown No problem! I posted an answer describing this. If it solved your problem could you accept it to close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of the `form` attribute within the `textarea`. You should only use the `form` attribute if the element is outside the form you are submitting.

For Example:

```
 <textarea rows="7" cols="82" name="mesaj" id="styled"></textarea>
```